# Dirichlet series for inverse of Eta function

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

We know that $$ \frac{1}{\zeta (s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s}} $$

but what happens with  $$ \frac{1}{\eta (s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b(n)}{n^{s}} $$

with $ \eta (s) =  (1-2^{1-s})\zeta (s) ?$

Can I evaluate the coefficients $ b(n) $ ? Perhaps I should apply the mobius transform to the sequence $ a(n)= (-1)^{n} .$

Comment: Isn't the term of "inverse" more attached to the meaning of "functional inverse" than, for instance, to the idea of "reciprocal"? So, perhaps you might consider to change the title to "reciprocal of eta"? *(We had on MO a discussion about the inverse of the zeta (and then eta) in the sense of a functional inverse, thus my impulse...)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find the coefficients $b(n)$ in different ways.

On the one hand, we can determine the Dirichlet inverse of $\alpha(n) = (-1)^{n-1}$. Since $\alpha$ is multiplicative, that is relatively easy, one finds

$$b(n) = \begin{cases} \mu(n) &, n \equiv 1 \pmod{2} \\ 2^{v_2(n)-1}\mu\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{v_2(n)}}\right)&, n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}. \end{cases}\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, from the product representation

$$\begin{align}
\eta(s) &= \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\prod_p \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\\
&= \frac{2^s-2}{2^s-1} \prod_{p > 2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}
\end{align}$$

by expanding

$$\frac{2^s-1}{2^s-2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^s-2} = 1 + \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{\nu-1}}{2^{\nu s}},$$

we obtain the product representation

$$\frac{1}{\eta(s)} = \left(1 + \sum_{\nu=1}^\infty \frac{2^{\nu-1}}{2^{\nu s}}\right)\prod_{p > 2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right),$$

which is easily seen to lead to $(1)$.

Comment: +1: I'll just add that $v2(n)$ is the valuation of $n$ relatively to $2$ (the power of $2$ in $n$) and this [link](https://oeis.org/A067856) (to see the first values at OEIS).

Comment: sorry did not understand  the part 'valuation of n relatively to the power of 2 ' could you put some example

Comment: @JoseGarcia If $p$ is a prime, the valuation of $n$ relatively to $p$ - denoted $v_p(n)$ - is the power of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $n$. So $p^{v_p(n)}$ divides $n$, but $p^{v_p(n) + 1}$ doesn't. Here we're looking at $p = 2$, and $v_2(n) = k$ if and only if $n = 2^k\cdot m$ with an odd $m$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{\eta(s)}=\frac1{(1-2^{1-s})\cdot\zeta(s)}=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b(n)}{n^{s}}\iff b(n)=\frac{\mu(n)}{1-2^{1-s}}$$

Comment: $b(n)$ should not depend on $s$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't really see how that would even be possible, given the fixed form of the right hand side. But, if someone were to prove me wrong, I'd be really interested.

Comment: @Lucian What do you mean, "fixed form of the right hand side"? The sequence $b(n)$, as OP notes (sort of), will be the Dirichlet inverse of the sequence $a(n)$, which exists because $a(1)\ne0$. Are you familiar with how Dirichlet series relate to Dirichlet convolution?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that $b(n)$ can be computed recursively as the Dirichlet inverse of $a(n)$. But there's another way: simply expand $(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}$ and multiply that against $\zeta(s)^{-1}$:

$$\frac{1}{\eta(s)}=\cfrac{1}{\displaystyle 1-\frac{2}{2^s}}\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\left(1+\frac{2}{2^s}+\frac{4}{4^s}+\frac{8}{8^s}+\cdots\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b(n)}{n^s} $$

Therefore, for $n$ odd, $b(n)=\mu(n)$, and for $n$ even,

$$\begin{array}{ll} b(n) & =\sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d=2^r}}d\mu(n/d) \\ & =\sum_{r=0}^{v}2^r\mu(n/2^r) \\ & =2^{v_2(n)}\mu(n/2^{v_2(n)})+2^{v_2(n)-1}\mu(n/2^{v_2(n)-1}) \\[3pt] & =2^{v_2(n)-1}\mu(n/2^{v_2(n)}).\end{array}$$

Comment: what is $ \nu_{2} (n) $ , also i need this formula to solve a physics problem so how should i quiote the answer in my vixra paper :) ?= thanks